# Which way is most efficient about calling C++ program on Hadoop(JNI, Hadoop Streaming, Pipes)

Tags: java, c++, hadoop

Recently, I need to run C++ project on Hadoop, after a deep survey, there are three ways to call C++ program on Hadoop(Java-version), namely Hadoop Streaming, Hadoop Pipes and JNI, I do not know which way is most efficient? Who can compare these three ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could set up a sample project and test it.  My guess would be that Hadoop Pipes might be slightly faster than Hadoop streaming because it skips the stdout/stdin buffer, and both might be faster than JNI since they allow nonjava binaries to be run directly in the reduce step, but that's just a guess.  I doubt the difference is big enough to be more important than using the way that keeps your code the simplest.